# String Modification On Pandas DataFrame Subset

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm having a hard time updating a string value in a subset of Pandas data frame

In the field action, I am able to modify the `action` column using regular expressions with:

`df['action'] = df.action.str.replace('([^a-z0-9\._]{2,})','')`

However, if the string contains a specific word, I don't want to modify it, so I tried to only update a subset like this:

`df[df['action'].str.contains('TIME')==False]['action'] = df[df['action'].str.contains('TIME')==False].action.str.replace('([^a-z0-9\._]{2,})','')`

and also using `.loc` like:

`df.loc('action',df.action.str.contains('TIME')==False) = df.loc('action',df.action.str.contains('TIME')==False).action.str.replace('([^a-z0-9\._]{2,})','')`

but in both cases, nothing gets updated. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide a sample dataframe, sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `loc` but you did it the way around with column first while it should be index first, and using `[]` and not `()`

```
mask_time = ~df['action'].str.contains('TIME') # same as df.action.str.contains('TIME')==False
df.loc[mask_time,'action'] = df.loc[mask_time,'action'].str.replace('([^a-z0-9\._]{2,})','')
```

example:

```
#dummy df
df = pd.DataFrame({'action': ['TIME 1', 'ABC 2']})
print (df)
   action
0  TIME 1
1   ABC 2
```

see the result after using above method:

```
   action
0  TIME 1
1       2
```

Comment: That worked, also helped me understand a little better how .loc works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work, I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41018073/5912896)

```
df.loc[df.action.str.contains('TIME')==False,'action'] = df.action.str.replace('([^a-z0-9\._]{2,})','')
```